# Need to read the excel attached in BMC Remedy incident via REST API

Tags: excel, rest, remedy

I need to read the excel attached within an incident in BMC Remedy. I am already connecting to Remedy via REST and can read the attachment but the thing is that it gets converted to String so only text based files like .txt, .log or .csv could be read but if at all the excel is attached obviously since it is not text based all I receive is gibberish.

So I am looking for a REST call that can read the excel and if cannot(which is quite possible) I am looking for a REST call with which I can download the excel locally.

Or if anyone has any other suggestion that would be really helpful

Comment: Can you share your rest call? according to the [documentation](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars91/en/entry-formname-entryid-attach-fieldname-609071440.html) of `/entry/{formName}/{entryId}/attach/{fieldName}` this should give the binary attachment... so I am curious as to what you are experiencing...

Comment: @JoSSte `https://servername:portname/api/arsys/v1/entry/HPD:WorkLog?q='Incident Number'="INC000075263242"` this is the link I use which will provide me details of all the attachments present for the provided Incident number ... in the details there would be one more link under z2AF Work Log01 json(this would be a child json)

Comment: And I perform another get call on that link to read the attachment's contents the response would again be a string based json(therefore in case of excel this method fails)

this would be the link:

`https://servername:port/api/arsys/v1/entry/HPD:WorkLog/WLG000032131748/attach/z2AF%20Work%20Log01`

Comment: I did try what you mentioned in the comment but it does not work it gives an error... because I am trying the with HPD:WorkLog as form name.

Comment: strange. have you searched arslist?

Comment: as far as I can tell, BMC states that they discard the Mime type, so your issue might be with the transmission of the data. are there any other servers than the J2EE (default= tomcat) between you and the server, that might interfere?

Comment: @JoSSte I don't think so that there is any other server in between.

Comment: I will see if I can reproduce it, I'll get back later...

Comment: Thanks buddy!! @JoSSte .. if you are giving it a shot please try with attachment as an excel and is attached in the worklog